# Erase backup files external hard drive

Tags: external-hdd

I'm looking for a way to delete automatic backup files (those on the form "filename.extension~") from a external hard drive, where I keep a backup from my main disk.

If the files were in /home, I could erase them with bleachbit or a similar program, like ubuntu tweak.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Are you looking for a GUI-way to do this or do you consider a terminal way also an answer?

Comment: There is no problem if I need to use the terminal to solve that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a command-line way of doing this using `find`. It's a little bit more advanced than using a GUI like Ubuntu Tweak, though.

1. Find the mount point of your external hard drive. Several ways exist:

   - In your file manager, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to get a text-based location bar. Copy this absolute location to your clipboard.
   - In a terminal identify the hard drive using `cat /proc/mounts` and locate the mount point. Example:

     ```
     /dev/sdc1 /media/1589-880A vfat rw,nosuid,[...]
     ```

     Indicates the mount point as `/media/1589-880A`.
2. Open a terminal and use the following `find` command to *list* the files matching the search we're performing. Replace the `/media` path here with the mount point you just found in the previous step. I've added `-type f` to filter for *files* only - disregarding links and directories.

   ```
   find /media/1589-880A -name "*~" -type f
   ```
3. If you feel happy about the results and you are sure you want to delete these files, then perform the delete like this:

   ```
   find /media/1589-880A -name "*~" -type f -delete
   ```

   **Note:** These files will *not* be sent to the Trash! They go to oblivion straight away. No easy undo exists. Don't ask for undoing this.

Feel free to modify the `*~` pattern to allow other matches for other use cases (e.g. `*.bak`, `autobackup-2012-*.tar.gz`, etc. It's just using plain shell globbing. It's also perfectly possible to select a sub folder or even a parent folder instead of the mount point. Anyway, always list first before deleting!

Optionally add `-xdev` to the `find` command to prevent it descending into other file systems if you're unsure about it.

Comment: Nice answer. There is a duplicate question on stackexchange that covers more then just the "~" files - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45800/locate-and-delete-all-temporary-files-in-user-directory

Comment: @bodhi.zazen That's a nice reference question. However that's a bit more advanced, covering more than just `*~` files and not taking the other mount point in account.

Comment: This is perfect. The fact I can see the files that will be deleted makes it even better.

Answer (score 1):

At a command line prompt in a shell, you can use a command like

```
rm -i *~
```

to delete from the current directory those files whose names end in ~.  The `-i` flag tells `rm` (the “remove” command) to inquire before deleting.  If you are not familiar with using shell commands, keep the `-i` flag in there until you are familiar, because minor errors like a space in the wrong place can have major consequences.

To list the files that will be affected in the current directory, you can say any of the following.

```
ls *~
ls -l *~
ls -la *~
```

To make a particular directory be the current working directory, use the `cd` command and the name of the directory.  For example, if you deduce that your backup disk is mounted at `/media/xyz` (either via the `cat /proc/mounts` command mentioned in another answer, or more directly via command `mount` with no parameters, or via `df`) you would say `cd /media/xyz` to make the top level directory of the backup drive the current working directory.

*Edit:* The `rm -i *~` command affects files only in the current directory, and does not affect subdirectories.  To treat indefinite levels of directories, use the `find` approach given in another answer.  However, if you know how deeply directories are nested, and the level is shallow, you might use a command like

```
rm -i  *~  */*~  */*/*~
```

which as shown would delete ~ files in the current directory, its direct subdirectories, and their direct subdirectories.

*Edit 2:* As gertvdijk mentions in a comment, the clumsy `rm` shown in previous edit can be streamlined by using `**` Bash 4.0+ recursive shell globbing ([1](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option)).  After the command `shopt -s globstar` has been entered, free-standing instances of `**` will glob recursively, ie will stand for all names in current directory and its descendants.  (`shopt -u globstar` turns `globstar` off, but since one is unlikely to type `**` by mistake it seems reasonable to leave it turned on in interactive shells.)  Thus, after `shopt -s globstar`,  the command `rm -i **/*~` will remove ~ files  in current directory and its descendants.  Note that if such filenames add up to more than a few million characters,  the command line may become too long for bash to handle.  The `find` approach does not have that particular limitation.

Comment: This will work as well, but require a lot of work if it's concerning a lot of directories to descend into. For just a few files I would prefer your approach, for a few more I would go for my `find` approach.

Comment: It seems to work very well and I liked the `-i` flag. But this is going to delete files only on the main directory or in the subfolders too?

Comment: @EduardoGoncalves, just in one directory.  See edit.

Comment: @jwpat7 Or just use [Bash 4.0+ recursive shell globbing](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2093/enable-to-expand-files-recursively-bash-4.0).